# Order in which properties are added to array.reduce() return object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Can anyone explain why the final output is the same in different uses of array.reduce() function?

In the first instance, the sample array is reduced directly whereas, in the second example, the sample array is first reversed and then reduced.

```
var array = [{
        "Id": "1",
        "Week": "2019-01-13"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Week": "2019-01-20"
    },
    {
        "Id": "3",
        "Week": "2019-01-27"
    }
];

array.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
    acc[curr.Id] = curr.Week;
    console.log(acc);
    return acc;
}, {});

//Output
/*{ "1": "2019-01-13" }
{ "1": "2019-01-13", "2": "2019-01-20" }
{ "1": "2019-01-13", "2": "2019-01-20", "3": "2019-01-27" }*/

array.reverse().reduce(function (acc, curr) {
    acc[curr.Id] = curr.Week;
    console.log(acc);
    return acc;
}, {});
//Output 
/*{ "3": "2019-01-27" }
{ "2": "2019-01-20", "3": "2019-01-27" }
{ "1": "2019-01-13", "2": "2019-01-20", "3": "2019-01-27" }
*/
```

I would like the output to appear as
{ "3": "2019-01-27", "2": "2019-01-20", "1": "2019-01-13" }.

If I use non numeric keys, the reduce function output in both scenarios are as expected(in the same order elements are passed).

Comment: Object by default have numerically ascending properties if your order is important you need to use array, you can read this [article](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/) for more detailed explanation

Comment: I want my output in a single object and not as an array of objects.

Comment: If you want an object with numeric keys, you can't control the order. The order is set in the spec.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the comments **object prop order is not guaranteed in JS** which is why you get that output. If you want order to matter you need to use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as your `reduce accumulator`.

> The Map object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original
>   insertion order of the keys.

With that said here is some sample code to illustrate it better:

```js
var array = [{ "Id": "1", "Week": "2019-01-13" }, { "Id": "2", "Week": "2019-01-20" }, { "Id": "3", "Week": "2019-01-27" } ];

let r1 = array.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  acc.set(curr.Id, curr.Week);
  return acc;
}, new Map());

let r2 = array.reverse().reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  acc.set(curr.Id, curr.Week);
  return acc;
}, new Map());

console.log('r1:')
r1.forEach(x => console.log(x))

console.log('r2:')
r2.forEach(x => console.log(x))

console.log('fromEntries:')
console.log(Object.fromEntries(r1))
console.log(Object.fromEntries(r2))
```

Notice how the order is different when we loop through the entries of the two maps (`r1` & `r2`). Also notice however that the moment you `convert` the maps to object literals the order is now the same since JS prop order is not guaranteed.